MissingSchemaError in mongoose
My schemas:
const facultySchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    groups: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Group'
    }]
})

export default model('Faculty', facultySchema)

const groupSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    students: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Student',
    }],
    journals: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Journal'
    }]
})

export default model('Group', groupSchema)

here is my service whe i have error MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Group". This error happend when i try to populate groups
class FacultyService {
    getFaculties = async () => {

        const faculties = await Faculty.find().populate('groups')

        if(!faculties) return null

        return faculties
    }
}

export const facultyService = new FacultyService()

when i add code const gr = await Group.find() to my getFaculties fucction error disappear.

You will need to import the Group model into the FacultyService module so that it's in scope.
